# Java Application : mouseDragged Event isn't Executed Often Enough

Tags: java, events, drag

Is there a way to make the mouseDragged Event be called more Often ( In my Case, Drawing a Color? I need it for Smooth Drawing, because right now, if you move too fast, it doesn't Draw All my Path. Also, I have an 2D Array Storing the Color of the Pixel, so that's also Problematic if I try to solve by problem by another Way, that's why I thought Increasing the mouseDragged Frequency would be the Best thing to Do

Thanks

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want smooth drawing, you'd likely have to interpolate the data yourself.  If you get an event at (3,3) and another at (10,10) you can figure the slope between the two, and iterate through the logical points that the mouse must have been dragged to get from (3,3) to (10,10)

I don't know of a way to force mouseDragged to update faster, and if, for instance the system was under high load, or someone used a touch screen, you might get huge jumps anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing ovals to as color lines, change to lines:

```
ArrayList<> colors;

mousepressed(Event e) {
    startPoint = e.getPoint();
}

mousedragged(Event e) {
    colors.add(new Color(startPoint, e.getPoint);
    startPoint = e.getPoint();
}

class Color() {

    Color(Point start, Point end) {
        // ...
    }

    paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(start, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I'm drawing Squares like 10X10 Pixels, and what happen with that there are gaps Between the Squares, because the mouseDragged Event isn't Executed enough times.

Comment: you can set the stroke with a g2 element `g2 = (Graphics2D) g` `g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10))`