# Java Swing mouseDragged callback speed

Tags: java, swing, mouse, drag

I have a question regarding the callback speed of the `mouseDragged` message of the `MouseMotionListener` in Java Swing. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886878/java-application-mousedragged-event-isnt-executed-often-enough) is sort of related but it's not entirely the same so I started a question of my own.

I'm making a small in-house application with no eye on commercial distribution that is basically a digitalized TCG (Trading Card Game) emulator. For any of you familiar with MtG (Magic the Gathering), you might've heard from such a similar program. I'm trying to create something that looks sort of like [this](http://www.4colorrebellion.com/media/pics/08/11/mtgo.jpg), but less fancy.

My GUI consists of a JFrame with menu and then some panels containing various buttons and labels, but I'll only go over the relevent parts to explain my problem.

In essence, I'm using a vertical split `JSplitPane` with a `JPanel` on the left, with in that a `JScrollPane` with a `JList` in it, which represents at any time the cards in your hand that you can play. On the right side of the split, I have a `JLayeredPane` with a background image in the `DEFAULT_LAYER` (subclass of `JPanel` that overrides the `draw` function to add an image) and, on various layers above the `PALETTE_LAYER`, I display the cards that are in play (gathered in an `ArrayList`) by means of custom `CardPanel`s (another subclass of `JPanel` that illustrates a card). The entire `JLayeredPane` is thus a representation of the table in front of you with all the cards you've already played.

I first started by adding a `MouseListener` and a `MouseMotionListener` to the `JLayeredPane` to pick up events, allowing me to register a mouse press, check if this was above a card, then use the mouse dragged event to move the card around and finally mouse release to place it back . This all works perfectly fine and if I add logging information I can see the `mouseDragged` callback function is called often, allowing for a visually fast dragging motion without lag.

Today I decided to add functionality to allow the user to drag a card from his hand to the "table" (instead of double clicking on the card in the `JList`), so I added the appropriate listeners to the `JList` along with filling in some functions like `MousePressed` and `MouseReleased`. On a mouse press, I check what card from the list was clicked, I lock the list, create a custom `CardPanel` (but don't add it anywhere yet, I just allocate and initiate it!) and set a flag. In mouse dragged, I check if this flag is set. If it is, I check where the cursor is. If it is anywhere above the `JLayeredPane`, I add the `CardPanel` to the `DRAG_LAYER` and set another flag. If this second flag is set in successive calls to mouse dragged, I don't add the panel again but I just change the location. This functionality is practically the same as the one in my previous mouse dragged callback. On mouse release, I unlock the list and add the `CardPanel` on the correct layer in the `JLayeredPane`.

Everything is working as intended so I'm pretty sure my code is okay, but there is just one slight issue:

When dragging a card from the list to the layered pane (instead of from the layered pane to the layered pane), I notice the `mouseDragged` callback is called at a pretty low frequency by the `JList` (approx 10 times per second), introducing some visually disturbing lag (compared to approx 30 times per second in the first case of dragging).

I'm going to add some code snippets as to clarify my problem but I'm afraid adding all the code to allow you to run it yourself would be serious overkill.

The main question in this post is: does anybody know why the `mouseDragged` is called faster by one `MouseMotionListener` than by another `MouseMotionListener`? The listener to the `JLayeredPane` component makes fast successive calls, the listener to the `JList` calls significantly slower.

**Note:** I'm developing in Netbeans and I'm using the built-in graphical Swing Interface Builder. I'm using a JFrame form as my main class.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    ...
    protected JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    protected JList cardsInHandList;
    ...

    ...
    protected ArrayList<String> cardsInHand;
    ...

    private void attachListeners(){
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                // set a flag, start a drag
            }
            public void MouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                // unset a flag, stop a drag
            }
        });
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void MouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                // drag the card around
                // gets called a lot!

                // actual code:
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                if (!dragging) return; // the flag

                int x = e.getX() - 10;
                int y = e.getY() - 10;

                // snap to grid
                x /= GRIDX;
                x *= GRIDX;

                y /= GRIDY;
                y *= GRIDY;

                // redraw the card at its new location
                draggedCard.setLocation(x, y);
            }
            }
        });

        cardsInHandList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                // set a flag, start a drag
            }
            public void MouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                // unset a flag, stop a drag
            }
        });
        cardsInHandList.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void MouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
                // check cursor location, drag if within bounds of layeredPane
                // gets called a whole lot less!! _Why?_

                // actual code:
            if (!draggingFromHand) return; // the flag

            // check location of cursor with own method (contains() didn't work for me)
            if (isCursorAtPointAboveLayeredPane(evt.getLocationOnScreen())) {

                // calculate where and snap to grid
                int x = (int) (evt.getLocationOnScreen().getX() - layeredPane.getLocationOnScreen().getX())-10;
                int y = (int) (evt.getLocationOnScreen().getY() - layeredPane.getLocationOnScreen().getY())-10;

                    // snap to grid
                x /= GRIDX;
                x *= GRIDX;
                y /= GRIDY;
                y *= GRIDY;

                    if(!draggingFromHandCardPanelAdded){
                        layeredPane.add(draggingFromHandCardPanel, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
                        draggingFromHandCardPanelAdded = true;
                    } else {
                    draggingFromHandCardPanel.setLocation(x,y);
                    }
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

I'll try to build a short runnable example reproducing the problem and then attach the code somewhere but right now I got to skoot.

Thanks in advance

**PS**: I am aware that there is another way to drag in Java, involving TransferHandlers and all that but it just seems like too much hassle and it isn't an actual answer to my question of how come the one callback seems to be called more than the other, so please don't tell me to use that instead.

Comment: maybe I split that to the 4. separated question, because hard to answer, maybe great posts by  @Hovercraft Full Of Eels can help you for one from 15th questions that I see there

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+DragLabelOnLayeredPane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you drag outside the list, Java start generating synthetic mouse events for the list, which might be the cause. See the javadoc for JComponent#setAutoscrolls(boolean).

You might get better results using a global event listener, see
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/